# Group all records by custom method in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to retrieve all records for a particular model and "index" each one by their `name` attribute.  The end result should be a Hash, where the keys are the name of the record, and the value is the record.  I can do this easy enough with a method like

```
def self.all_by_name
  hash = {}
  all.each { |model| hash[model.name] = model }
  hash
end
```

Is there a way to do this with an active record query?

Answer (score 0):

`all.group(:name)` is what you need!

Some documentation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-group

Comment: That was my first attempt, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

No, active record will either return an array or an active record relation. You would have to massage it after into the data type of your choice. ActiveRecor dcan return anything that SQL can normally return. However, you could do use the `group` method which is essentially the `group by` in SQL.

I'm not sure in your case what your method should do because it seems like you are going to overwrite the value of your key if there are 2 objects with the same class. Perhaps if you better defined what you need in an example I could help you better.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I'm just converting an array into a hash so I can take advantage of hashing to lookup objects.  I'm working with an expensive algorithm, so it's faster to hash these objects one time, up front, instead of constantly iterating through arrays.  The model names are unique so there's no worry about overwriting.  This is a common technique, so I was hoping there was simple method I didn't know about.